# I am trying to add a router to my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component display's a list of titles and when you click on a title at the top of the page the body of the post is displayed. I have the component that display's the body of the post in a different component.

I want to create a Router file that will switch between Post and Posts depending on the id that is givin by the Posts title.

This is my Routes

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import Posts  from './components/posts';
import Post  from './components/post';

// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Router location. */
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

/**
 * Component used to render the app routes.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Routes = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { location } = props;

    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
  <div>
   <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
   <Route path="/post/:id" exact component={Post} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Routes.propTypes = propTypes;

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

This is my Posts that displayed all the titles and when you click on the title it passes it to Post component to be displayed at the top of the page. I want to change this so that it links and goes to the Post page and passes the id to the post page.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import useReduxApi from '@cparram/use-redux-api';
import Post from "./post";

const Posts = props => {
  const [api, apiCall] = useReduxApi("posts");

  // Call api on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall({
      endpoint: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    });
  }, []);

  const [selectedPostId, setPostId] = useState(null);
  const preventDefault = event => event.preventDefault();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <h5>Select one item</h5>
      {!api.fetching &&
        api.data &&
        api.data.map(post => (
          <Link to='/post/id' onClick={preventDefault}>
         <div key={post.id} onClick={() => setPostId(post.id)}>
            {`title: ${post.title}`}
          </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};



export default Posts;
```

And this is my post

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import useReduxApi from '@cparram/use-redux-api';

const Post = props => {
  const { id } = props;
  const [{ fetching, data: post }, apiCall] = useReduxApi(`post-${id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall({
      endpoint: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
    });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {fetching && `Loading post with id ${id}...`}
      <p>{!fetching && post && `body: ${post.title}`}</p>
      <p>{!fetching && post && `body: ${post.body}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};



export default Post;
```

I created a Link in posts to link to my post page but this does not work. I dont tknow if my router is wrong of my link

codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wave-1io99

Comment: You use withRouter outside the scope of BrowserRouter. Remove withRouter from routes

Comment: @gaditzkhori  Ok this worked but when I go to localhost:3000/post/1 I see the Posts page instead of the single post

Comment: Pass the exact attribute to this  <Route path="/" exact component={Posts} />
That makes it unique. Without exact it would consider posts/1 as /.

Comment: OK my localhost:3000/post/1 works but when I try to add a link in my posts and link to post I cannot get it to work. I updated mu question so you can see

Comment: But I am not doing a api call I am routing to /posts/post.id. Or how would I create a link to this component and send the id

Comment: Your post list should Link to post/id. then in post component you should get the id from the param using props.match.params and fetch api in useEffect. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: @gaditzkhori I updated my question... still cant get it to work... Sorry I am new to react

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-burnell-qhq4x

Comment: I get this error with your code Cannot read property 'params' of undefined. Does this mean I have to import params or the id is no defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const Post = props => {
  const [{ fetching, data: post }, apiCall] = useReduxApi();

  useEffect(() => {
   if(props.match.params.id){
    apiCall({
      endpoint: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${
        props.match.params.id
      }`
    });
   }
  }, [props.match.params.id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {fetching && `Loading post with id ${props.match.params.id}...`}
      <p>{!fetching && post && `body: ${post.title}`}</p>
      <p>{!fetching && post && `body: ${post.body}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import useReduxApi from '@cparram/use-redux-api';
// import Post from "./post";

const Posts = props => {
  const [api, apiCall] = useReduxApi("posts");

  // Call api on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall({
      endpoint: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    });
  }, []);

  // const [selectedPostId, setPostId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <h5>Select one item</h5>
      {/* {selectedPostId && <Post id={selectedPostId} />} */}
      {api.fetching && "Loading posts ..."}
      {!api.fetching &&
        api.data &&
        api.data.map(post => (
          <Link to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
            {`title: ${post.title}`}
          </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```